# Confusion with spring @ManyToMany

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, orm

i have product and campaign entity with ManyToMany relationship.
When I define a campaign for the product, I add something like this to the product_campaigns table in the db.
For example:

```
product_campaigns : product_id : 1 campaign_id : 1
```

It means that  campaign with 1 id is defined for the product with 1 id.
When I delete the campaign number 1, I want the lines with the number 1 campaign defined in the product_campaigns table to be deleted.
But now when i delete the campaign number 1 ,it both deletes the product_campaigns row and deletes the related product object in the product table
. What am i wrong ? Thx.

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class Product extends BaseExtendedModel {


    private String name;
    private BigDecimal price;
    private UUID barcode;
    private String image;

    @ManyToOne
    private Brand brand;
    @ManyToOne
    private Category category;
    @ManyToOne
    private Seller seller;

    private int stock;

    private BigDecimal taxRate;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "PRODUCT_CAMPAIGN", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "product_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "campaign_id") })
    private Set<Campaign> campaigns = new HashSet<>();

}
```

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Campaign extends BaseModel{

    private BigDecimal discountRate;
    private BigDecimal discountPrice;
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "campaigns",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Product> productSet = new HashSet<>();

}
```

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CampaignServiceImpl implements CampaignService{
    private final CampaignRepository campaignRepository;
    private final CampaignConverter campaignConverter;
    @Override
    public void create(CreateCampaignRequestDTO createCampaignRequestDTO) {
        Campaign campaign = campaignConverter.toCampaign(createCampaignRequestDTO);
        campaignRepository.save(campaign);
    }
    public Campaign getCampaign(Long campaignId){
        return campaignRepository.findById(campaignId).orElseThrow(
                () -> new BusinessServiceOperationException.CampaignNotFoundException("Campaign not found")
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Long campaignId) {
        Campaign campaign = getCampaign(campaignId);
        campaignRepository.delete(campaign);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deleting you have to pay attention to your cascade types. `CascadeType.ALL` includes `REMOVE` so you're telling spring data to delete all the items in the `productSet`.

What you want is `CascadeType.PERSIST`, also add the `@JoinTable` annotation.

```java
@Entity
public class Campaign extends BaseModel {

    // your other code

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "campaigns", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinTable(
        name = "PRODUCT_CAMPAIGN", 
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "campaign_id"), 
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id"))
    private Set<Product> productSet = new HashSet<>();

}
```

Link to documentation: https://openjpa.apache.org/builds/2.4.0/apache-openjpa/docs/jpa_overview_meta_field.html#jpa_overview_meta_cascade