# JPA - Does @OneToMany demand @ManyToOne?

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-many, many-to-one

I am developing an application with JPA and I came across a small problem.

I have this two entities Category and Supplier.

A Supplier must have at least one category so I used the @OneToMany tag.

```
@Entity
public class Supplier extends AbstractEntity {
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;
    @NotEmpty
    private String address;

   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "supplier")
   private List<Category> categories = new LinkedList<>();


    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return this.address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }


   public List<Category> getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }

    public void setCategories(List<Category> categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }

    //TO DO : Add verification to ensure that a Supplier has at least a supplied category
    //TO DO : add a method do add a category to supplied categories
}
```

On the other end since I used the @OneToMany tag in the Supplier entity I ended up using the @ManyToOne tag in Category entity.

```
@Entity
public class Category extends AbstractEntity{
    @NotBlank
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "supplier_id")
    @NotNull
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"categories"})
    private Supplier supplier;

    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

}
```

But this creates a little problem.

Anytime that I want to create a new Category I need to provide a Supplier to it, which is not the intended behavior.

How can I get around this? Can I remove the @ManyToOne tag in Category?

Comment: So you are saying that it is possible for a category to NOT have a supplier?   OK then, just remove the @NotNull (and also remove the “NOT NULL” from the database column).

Comment: Can I also remove the class variable suppplier?

Comment: I have a form to create a new Category and in that form I don't want to have a field for the Supplier

Comment: Once you remove the @NotNull, then there is no reason for it to be populated (and therefore it is OK for it to not appear on a form).

Comment: But since I don't want that my Category table to have a supplier column isn't it better to remove the  class variable?

Comment: Is it valid for a category to ever have a supplier ?  If so, then category should have a supplier column.  If not, then why did you have a supplier column there in the first place?

Comment: I added the supplier column because I fought it was mandatory because of @OneToMany tag in Supplier.java

Comment: Ah, so sounds like you aree actually after a ManyToMany relationship - basically a separate table connecting suppliers to categories.  Of course, this implicitly allows each category to have multiple suppliers, so your application will have to restrict that if that’s not what you want. Implement that either by the @ManyToMany annotation, or create the joining “SupplierCatwgories” table+class yourself (that has ManyToOne to both  Supplier and Category)

Comment: can you show an example?

Comment: Something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/72106024/681444

Comment: OneToMany can use a join table too, see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany#Example_of_a_OneToMany_using_a_JoinTable_database . Your provider then can put in the constraints on the join table to enforce uniqueness so that one category only has one supplier if that is required. Otherwise, it is the same as a ManyToMany